# Maven and XSD [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate (default): Unable to parse input schema(s)

Tags: xml, maven, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am working on an application which had many maxOccurs="unbounded" in the XSD files like

```
<xs:element name="bar" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

and

```
<xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

I learnt that this a actually a vulnerability to keep it unbounded and I changed it to first **"4095"** and then to **"100"** and on running mvn clean install, both are throwing the following errors

```
[INFO] --- jaxb2:0.12.3:generate (default)
[INFO] Up-to-date check for source resources [[file: filesnames..... ]]
[INFO] Sources are not up-to-date, XJC will be executed.          
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate (default) on project projectName: Unable to parse input schema(s). Error messages should have been provided. -> [Help 1]
```

How to solve this? Also what is the maximum number which can be used in maxOccurences?

Comment: Maybe the namespace prefixes? You once wrote `xs:` and the next time `xsd:`.

Comment: @Karsten yes we have both kind of files

Comment: I have no problems compiling this to Java code, What errors have been provided? Without the relevant parts I can't help.

Comment: @Karsten when it is 100 it is working fine but when it is 4095 it throws [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate (default) on project projectName: Unable to parse input schema(s). Error messages should have been provided. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have had serious problems with the maven-jaxb2-plugin too and again it's frustrating because I can't find the extremely useful Maven Plugin Documentation.

Since these days I go with the [org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxb2-maven-plugin).

If you don't want to switch to the jaxb2-maven-plugin you should consider to use a newer version of your plugin at least. Version 0.15.3 worked for me finally.

Some notes:

- With 0.12.3 I needed to add some dependencies to the plugin to get it halfway working which I had to remove with 0.15.3.
- The whole javax classes have moved to jakarta now. Thus maybe the most recent plugin versions don't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Karsten response

If you want to know how to get latest version of highsource's maven-jaxb2-plugin, feel free to [check the migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide)

We did many refactoring in order to provide best jakarta support in latest versions (starting from v3)